# Derive Union Type from an Observable of array values at runtime

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have a Typescript code with the next type definition:

```
export type MeasurementContext = 'height' | 'speed' | 'temperature';
```

I'd like to derive that list of Measurements from a Configuration request to the Server at execution time instead of take from const values, but I cannot get it working.

I tried using something like this:

```
let list = getConfigMeasurements() as const // returns ['height' | 'speed' | 'temperature']
type NeededUnionType = typeof list[number]; // 'height'|'speed'|'temperature';
```

But it returns number is a type but is used like a variable.

Answer (score 1):

"I'd like to derive that list of measurements from a configuration request to the server at execution time".

Typescript types don't exist in run time, they are all stripped out the second the program compiles; There are some ways to generate code based on types leveraging the typescript-transformer API however.... for this case i would say it doesn't fall under idiomatic typescript and thus should be avoided.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure

Comment: Yes, I knew this afirmation but I was thinking anyway to get at runtime because I don't know the union types before the class evaluates within any method. I will take your answer under consideration.